# How to reinstall ubuntu 14.04 without cd drive or usb

Tags: 14.04, reinstall

I want to reinstall ubuntu 14.04, but the cd drive of my laptop isnt working and my laptop is old so it cant boot from usb sticks. What can i do?

Comment: A hard work-around, but could you boot from the network?

Comment: i can downlaod ubuntu 14.04 32 bit, but i dont know how to install it.

Comment: Do i have to use the terminal to install it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have grub installed, you could boot directly from the iso file you downloaded.

First run: `sudo apt-get install grml-rescueboot`

Then move your iso file to the `/boot/grml` folder with: `sudo mv ~/Downloads/filename.iso /boot/grml/`. Change the filename and its path accordingly.

Then update grub with: `sudo update-grub`. If this doesn't work, you could create a manual entry in grub.

Open the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file with `sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom` and add the following lines:

```
 menuentry "Ubuntu 12.04 ISO" {
     set isofile="/home/<username>/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso"
     # or set isofile="/<username>/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso"
     # if you use a single partition for your $HOME
     loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
     linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
     initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
 }
```

Modify accordingly.

Reboot your computer and you should find a new menu entry in Grub associated with your ISO file. Choose this open and install as usual.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: done, but what to do next?

Comment: Reboot and there should be an entry for your ISO. Choose it and it should boot it.

Comment: didnt work. some errors appeared by installing the grub loader

Comment: Which errors? Can you be more specific? Did you modify the text to match your iso?

Comment: i have copied them from the terminal, but they are to long to paste them here