# Reinstall Ubuntu without any USB/CD/DVD

Tags: boot, partitioning

I screwed up my Ubuntu system, so now I need to format and reinstall Ubuntu, but I don't have any USB drives or CD/DVDs

[image]

It looks like this now. I only have Ubuntu, so I don't have dualboot of any kind.

I was thinking about creating a new partition from the unused space in /dev/sda2 for my backup stuff and then create another partition to install a bootable Ubuntu on, then I'll boot into that bootable partition and then format and install Ubuntu on /dev/sda2 again.

Is it possible for me to achieve something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to install Ubuntu without a CD or USB drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59347/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-without-a-cd-or-usb-drive)

Comment: As shown on the image I only have Ubuntu and nothing else. I also tried this: http://askubuntu.com/a/555901/34385 but this isn't working either as it creates something called "isodevice" and then I can't shrinken my root partition

Comment: Sorry did not realize most answers were based on Windows. I will write you a new answer then for netboot from Ubuntu.

Comment: When you say you've screwed your Ubuntu, it still boots right?

Comment: Yes, this screenshot is taken from my system in openbox, as lightdm and unity are not working and my ubuntu is super slow. I did report this to launchpad also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1522596 dont know if it helps in anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way which requires an rooted Android device.

You need to download this app: [DriveDroid - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid&hl=da). And move a Ubuntu iso file to your Android device and use the app to make Android bootable with that iso and then use your computer to boot from it.

[image]

I had issues with I couldn't do anything with my /dev/sda2 partition even when booting from Android. So I downloaded [GParted live iso](http://gparted.org/download.php) and used GParted to shrinken my root partition and make a backup partition, then I used Ubuntu to move my files from my root partition to the new backup partition.

Then set Android to be a Ubuntu bootable again and install ubuntu from there. Then copy my files and used gparted again to make my new ubuntu use the old backup partition.

Comment: +1 Don't forget, you can accept your own answer, so people know it is the correct one.

Comment: I had to wait 24hours first, then I just forgot it :P

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, you must have a wired internet connection to use netboot.

Download the appropriate `initrd.gz` file and the appropriate `linux` file for your architecture and distribution from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/).

Save them inside /boot. (These files are quite small, under 10MB for either architecture.)

Reboot your computer and enter the grub menu. Now we will get grub to boot from the files you just downloaded.

Press <kbd>c</kbd> to get a grub command prompt. Type each of the following lines:

```
root=(hd0,1)
```

Replace hd0,1 with the drive and partition on which your /boot is located. You can look at and copy the root line of any existing boot menu entry if you are at all unsure what this is, or you can try tab-completing after root ( or root (hd0,.

Now type

```
linux /boot/linux
```

Then

```
initrd /boot/initrd.gz
```

Finally type

```
boot
```

Your system should now boot into the Ubuntu installer. Follow the instructions from there.

Here is the [official documentation for netboot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet).

Comment: when you say "appropriate initrd.gz and linux files" what is it? http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/ I downloaded the initrd.gz from there something else I need to download?

Comment: The one called `linux` too. Hopefully my edit addresses this issue for you.

Comment: I need internet connection, i only have wifi. How do i connect to wifi in this netboot?

Comment: What do you see ? A terminal or an error ? What ? Documentation just says it will run an installer.

Comment: After i have choose keyboard layout it does a configure network with dhcp and fails "network autoconfiguration failed" but i never gave my wifi info. I only have android phone hotspot so i dont any router or ethernet cable connection. I can do a "Configure network manually" but i think thats for manual local ip setup instead of using dhcp(so i cant do it through wifi??)

Comment: If it was possible to shrinken my root partition(dev/sda2) i would be able to use this solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/555901/34385

Comment: You can't shrink the boot partition if you are using it, don't know what to tell you, usb tether maybe ? without access to a router this can't be done on wifi it seems. There is one more way `debootstrap` but this is complex, read the `without cd` section at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux

Comment: I'll just give up and go out and buy a usb drive :P

Comment: If you can add to the answer that it cant be done without a ethernet cable, i'll mark your answer as accepted :)

Comment: Looking at `debootstrap`, I too would wait to buy a USB :)

Comment: I found something completly else: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid i used this and booted gparted iso, cause ubuntu mounted my root partition so i couldnt shrink it but i can on gparted livecd. I needed an rooted android device and a usb cable :)

Comment: @Jeggy Nice find :) I always thought, an Android phone would have issues being mounted at boot but I guess not. You should write and accept your own answer for this, it is good, useful information.